# Installing composer on OSX getting no such file or directory

Tags: macos, terminal, composer-php

Im trying to install composer, iv tried for hours but it just wont work

i follow the steps like so

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Thats successful, i get this result

```
Use it: php composer.phar
```

Then i add this:

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

And it doesnt work, i get this result

```
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory
```

When i echo $PATH, i get this

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I followed your steps on my Mac (running Yosemite), and it worked fine for me. One thing that does come to mind, though, is the current working directory you are in.

*I'd make this a comment if I could,* but have you tried ls'ing where you are to make sure the composer.phar file isn't somewhere else?